# Python - search and replace broken up text in HTML

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

I have been using a tool to convert pdf documents to HTML so that they can be more easily edited while retaining as much formatting as possible. What I need to do is replace certain phrases with the text "[REDACTED]", the problem is that this text is unpredictably broken up by random tags (mostly span tags) so I cannot easily just use find and replace.

As an example I need to replace the text "Sensitive Information to Remove" from this html snippet:

```
<span class="fs4 fc2">Sensitive<span class="_ _b"> </span>Information to Re<span class="_ _c"></span>move</span>
```

With this:

```
<span class="fs4 fc2">[REDACTED]</span>
```

Is there any way of accomplishing this using a library like Beautiful Soup or some sort of sophisticated regex string?

Comment: bs4 is more likely to work than regex, but what have you tried so far?

Comment: So I first discovered that this code wasn't working:
`target = html_soup.find_all(text=sensitive_info)`

`        for v in target:`

`            v.replace_with(v.replace(sensitive_info, "[REDACTED]"))`

And I tried to see if there was some sort of pattern with how the text is broken up and no luck on that front. Searched Stack Overflow if anyone has had a similar problem and also haven't found anything, so I am quite stuck...

Comment: What is the tool you are using? I wonder why there is some tool will insert random garbage during conversion.

Comment: It's called pdf2htmlex: https://github.com/coolwanglu/pdf2htmlEX

I mean if you know another python-supported way of being able to find and replace text in a pdf while retaining it's format, that would also solve my problem :)

Comment: I think looping through all the spans and then getting the text of what's inside them would be at least a partial solution: `for span in soup.find_all('span'):` then `text = span.get_text()` then `if text == "Sensitive Information to Remove":` because get_text removes all tags within an element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For replacing text in HTML document you can use `clear()` and `append()` methods BeautifulSoup provides ([manual pages](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#clear)):

```
data = """<span class="fs4 fc2">Sensitive<span class="_ _b"> </span>Information to Re<span class="_ _c"></span>move</span>"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')

secret_string = "Sensitive Information to Remove"
redacted_string = "[REDACTED]"

while True:
    s = soup.body.find(lambda t: t.text==secret_string)
    if not s:
        break

    s.clear()
    s.append(redacted_string)

print(soup)
```

This will print:

```
<html><body><span class="fs4 fc2">[REDACTED]</span></body></html>
```